How to get all installed applications and their detailed info on Mac? (Not just running apps)
NSWorkspace has https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications, which returns a list of NSRunningApplication.
NSRunningApplication provides icon, bundleURL, executableURL, etc, and also methods like terminate().
I am looking for the same thing for other installed but not running applications.
I know system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType returns a list of applications, but it doesn't provide the information I need.

I define application as a regular app that can be launched like Chrome. I thought about searching /Applications folder. But I have to keep searching for the main executable, and app icon. Some apps have many icons. I wonder how apple do this with the native APIs.

Bundle works great, but missing properties like icon, localizedName. It gives me bundleIdentifier, executablePath though.
Another (non-perfect) option I just found is simply parse the plist file. It contains icon path and pretty much everything I need. Still wish there is a more elegant solution like NSRunningApplication or Bundle .

I worked on this problem professionally over the course of a couple of years, including a couple of DTS's with Apple. There is no comprehensive, reliable solution. There isn't even a perfectly applicable definition of an "application" is or what it means for it to be "installed." There are a bunch of heuristics. Before the Mac App Store, Apple long prided itself on drag and drop install, so there's nothing like the Windows Add/Remove Programs system. A program is "installed" by existing.
Looking in /Applications and ~/Applications is a good first start. You may also find the following useful:

/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump
pkgutil --pkgs
mdfind "kMDItemKind == 'Application'"

The last one is a great tool because it's so incredibly fast. It's also a bit unreliable if the Spotlight database hasn't been updated yet (such as immediately after a machine has been cloned). Spotlight knows when the first scan is done because until then it puts a little dot in its icon to tell you it's not quite ready. There is no API to request that status (at least there wasn't when I was working on this problem).
Once you have a path, you can use things like mdls to query other info.
Note that Apple has changed a lot of things over the years, so if you need to support a lot of OS versions, be sure to test on those OS versions. Apple has been making some of this stuff more of a black box rather than less. Tools like LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier are now deprecated, and I'm not aware of any replacement.
Generally, your problem will be finding too much stuff rather than too little. You may be surprised how many "applications" are actually on a system. I have nearly 600, including:
/Library/Application Support/Script Editor/Templates/Droplets/Recursive File Processing Droplet.app
/Library/Application Support/Script Editor/Templates/Droplets/Droplet with Settable Properties.app
/Library/Application Support/Script Editor/Templates/Droplets/Recursive Image File Processing Droplet.app
/Library/Application Support/Script Editor/Templates/Cocoa-AppleScript Applet.app

and also:
/Users/rnapier/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/8.0/LocalInstall/Installer.Backup/11-8.10.4.11/Visual Studio Update.app

Another very hard problem you may run into is that there is no hierarchy. An app is an app. In my experience, problems in this space often want to register that "Microsoft Office" is installed, but there's no "app" called "Microsoft Office." It's implied by having various other apps installed. That is definitely something you have to compile yourself. When I was working in this space, a big piece of the value was having a massive database accumulated over years of how every version of every app known to humanity mapped to various artifacts so that it could be displayed in a useful form. Knowing all those details and the thousand exceptions is the real heart of system management systems.

You can enumerate the files in the /Applications directory, or /System/Applications directory, or ~/Applications directory, or wherever else you assume the "installed" applications will be.
guard let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(
    at: URL(filePath: "/Applications"),
    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
    options: [.skipsPackageDescendants]
) else { return }
for case let url as URL in enumerator {
    // ...
}

Assuming all "applications" have a bundle (simple executable files don't), you can try creating a Bundle from it and get the information you need.
guard let bundle = Bundle(url: url) else { continue }
print(bundle.executableURL)
print(bundle.bundleIdentifier)
print(bundle.infoDictionary)

Use infoDictionary to access the keys in its Info.plist file. See the available keys here.
To get the icon, you can do:
if let dict = bundle.infoDictionary,
   let iconName = dict["CFBundleIconFile" /* or CFBundleIconName for newer versions*/] as? String,
   let url = bundle.urlForImageResource(iconName) {
    NSImage(contentsOf: url) // or whatever else you want...
}

